# 2 Proportion Z-tests with NSDUH survey data

Tags: r, hypothesis-test, proportions

I'm working with data tables from [2020 NSDUH data](https://www.samhsa.gov/data/data-we-collect/nsduh-national-survey-drug-use-and-health). The data tables I have access to give me the following information:

- estimated percentage of people with a substance use disorder
- estimated number of people with a substance use disorder (for the entire US)
- sample size
- standard error

I would like to use a 2 Proportion Z-test to see if there is a statistically significantly difference between people with a substance use disorder based on their type of insurance. In R, prop.test requires you have the number of "successes", but I don't have the raw data to populate that info accurately.

Is there another way to do this or different test I should use that would allow me to use the proportions that have already been calculated along with the standard error?

Here is some sample data

```
idd_all <- matrix(c(36280,  0.066,  0.0021, 
                    23690,  0.053,  0.0024,
                    6990,   0.118,  0.0067), 
                  byrow = T, nrow = 3, ncol = 3,
                  dimnames = list(c("total", "medicaid 12+", "private 12+"),
                                  c("sample size", "% IDD", "SE")))
```

|  | sample size | est % IDD | SE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| total | 36280 | 0.066 | 0.0021 |
| medicaid 12+ | 23690 | 0.053 | 0.0024 |
| private 12+ | 6990 | 0.118 | 0.0067 |

note: There are obviously more insurance types that we are not interested in, we want primarily interested in the difference between people on Medicaid and privately insured individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following answers your question on how to test the null hypothesis of equal proportions between `medicaid 12+` and `private 12+`.

```
total_medicaid <- 23690 / 0.053
total_private <- 6990 / 0.118

x <- c(23690, 6990)
n <- c(total_medicaid, total_private)
prop.test(x, n)
```

**Result**

```
# 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
# 
# data:  x out of n
# X-squared = 3880.4, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   -0.06768921 -0.06231079
# sample estimates:
#   prop 1 prop 2 
# 0.053  0.118
```